# How to rename column in one-to-many relation in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a League class which contains Teams property, which is a collection of teams as shown below:

```
public class LeagueEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int LeagueId { get; set; }
    ...
    [Required]
    public ICollection<TeamEntity> Teams { get; set; }
}


public class TeamEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(10)")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(300)]
    public string Logo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string IsNational { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Founded { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public VenueEntity Venue { get; set; }
}
```

When i update the database, two tables are created - Leagues and Teams. In Teams table i have a column which is foreign key pointing to the correct league, where the team belongs to. The column is named "LeagueEntityLeagueId". How to rename it?

Answer (score 5):

Make the `foreign key` explicit as follows:

```
public class TeamEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("League")]
    public int LeagueId { get; set; } //  You can give the whatever name you want

    .........

    public LeagueEntity League {get; set;}

}
```

If you don't want explicit foreign key and navigation property then you can do as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

     modelBuilder.Entity<LeagueEntity>().HasMany(l => l.Teams).WithOne().HasForeignKey("LeagueId");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In TeamEntity Table add the following  property

```
  public int LeagueId { get; set; }
  public virtual LeagueEntity LeagueEntity { get; set; }
```